# Fetching and comparing data with React and RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm working on a React application that utilizes RTK Query for data fetching. I have a query that takes `from` and `to` dates as parameters and fetches data accordingly.

I have a component structure like this:

```
export function MyComponent({ comparePeriods }: { comparePeriods: IComparePeriod[] }) {
    // Default dates
    const initialFrom = '2022-01-01';
    const initialTo = '2023-01-01';

    // Fetch data with initial dates
    const { data } = useGetDataQuery({ from: initialFrom, to: initialTo });

    // How can I modify this component to fetch and store data for each compare period?
    // Additionally, how can I select the data from each request with different dates and display it here?

    return <div>Data here</div>;
}

export interface IComparePeriod {
    from: string;
    to: string;
}
```

The component initially fetches data with some default dates (`initialFrom` and `initialTo`). However, I want to allow the user to select additional compare periods and fetch the corresponding data to compare with the initial data.

I'm looking for guidance on the best practices or official approaches for handling this kind of scenario with React and RTK Query. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!